# php require path on Bluehost

Tags: php, include, require

Today is the first time that that I want to upload a project that I programmed from scratch with php to my bluehost account. I managed to set everythign up except my include paths. I have tried for many times but still get the following errors.

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(Classes/ini_classes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/rodneywo/public_html/reg/index.php on line 2
[11-Mar-2016 08:18:32 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Classes/ini_classes.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in /home1/rodneywo/public_html/reg/index.php on line 2
[11-Mar-2016 08:19:04 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  require_once(Classes/ini_classes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/rodneywo/public_html/reg/index.php on line 2
[11-Mar-2016 08:19:04 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Classes/ini_classes.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in /home1/rodneywo/public_html/reg/index.php on line 2
[11-Mar-2016 08:34:59 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  require_once(Classes/ini_classes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/rodneywo/public_html/reg/index.php on line 2
```

```
<?php
     require_once('Classes/Database_connection.php');
     require_once('Classes/Database.php');
     require_once('Classes/functions.php');

     require_once('Classes/Customer.php');`enter code here`
     require_once('Classes/Project.php');
     require_once('Classes/Session.php');
     require_once('Classes/Pagination.php');
     require_once('Classes/fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Have you added the path to the scripts?

Comment: What is the question? The error message seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: require_once('/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear/Classes/Project.php'); I thought this would work, but it didn't.